# orderby with eager loading, laravel

Tags: eloquent, eager-loading, laravel-5.6

I have a table called chat which is joined with users and messages (messages are joined with users), the query works fine just I am trying to add orderby with created_at (desc) but it has to be from the table messages. help me out here. Thanks in advance. Below is my query,

```php
return new GroupDirectChat(
    Chat::with(['messages.users', 'users' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('id', '!=', Auth::id());
    }])
        ->where('direct_chat', 1)
        ->whereHas('users', function ($query) {
            $query->where('id', '=', Auth::id());
        })
        ->get()
);
```

Comment: Do you want to order `chats` by `messages.created_at`?

Comment: I guess you would need join to sort results using attribute of related table

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir yes

Comment: A `chat` can have multiple `messages`. Which one do you want to use for ordering? The latest one?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir yes a chat can have many messages but i just want to display the latest one, currently m using take(1) from messages table but not the latest one.

Answer (score 0):

Combine a JOIN with a subquery:

```php
$chats = Chat::select('chats.*')
    ->join('messages', 'messages.chat_id', 'chats.id')
    ->where('chats.direct_chat', 1)
    ->where('messages.id', function ($query) {
        $query->select('id')
            ->from('messages')
            ->whereColumn('chat_id', 'chats.id')
            ->latest()
            ->limit(1);
    })
    ->whereHas('users', function ($query) {
        $query->where('id', '=', Auth::id());
    })
    ->latest('messages.created_at')
    ->with(['messages.users', 'users' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('id', '!=', Auth::id());
    }])
    ->get();
```

Note that this query only selects chats with at least one message.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jonas, Ill definitely give this a try and get back here.

Comment: Unfortunately it display all the messages (not by latest) related to chat.

Comment: I have fixed it by using order by for messages in chats model

Comment: Do you mean the eagerly loaded messages? Can you post the changes?